# How to create BackButton on UINavigationController in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I follow some tutorials, but then the back button is created automatically. I create a new view controller, and set navigation show to plus button at navigation bar. But when navigates to new view controller, not have the button to back to previus view controller.

[image]

I'm here:

[image]

Comment: Did you use **show** in the segue ?

Comment: @Nitish yes, only show option

Comment: Can you show the code in second VC's viewDidLoad ? And also the code in VC1's prepareForSegue ?

Comment: I did no create yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ViewController` where you put the `tableView`. Tap on that `ViewController` and then go to -

**EDITOR(on top of xcode)-> EMBED IN ->NAVIGATION CONTROLLER**

Run your project. Now you will see a back button in your new `ViewController`.

Comment: this create a viewcontrolle before my main view controller. bad reply.

Comment: :) this viewcontroller will not show when you run your project. Did u run your project after embed in the navigation controller?

Comment: In the examples this not happens. And makes my storyboard unreadable, you reply is correct, but not for my case.

Comment: Click on the yellow dot on your viewcontroller the first one (Title). Then embed in  navigation controller. Run your project. Definitely you will see the back button.

Comment: I think what @Augusto meant in this question was, that when adding a segue, Back button is not visible in storyboard, which appears otherwise on using nav controller. There is no involvement of running the project.

Comment: my reply was for the first line - (this create a viewcontrolle before my main view controller.). what i want to describe is that adding navigation cont. will not add another ViewController.

Comment: You right! I'am did make wrong way to create a navigation controller. Now is working!

Comment: But, this works when I remove my TabBar, how I put both works?

Comment: add the tabbar item in your navigation controller. it will work

Comment: You just save my day.

Comment: Glad to hear that once again :)

Comment: taking advantage of your goodwill, how do I insert a title into the created view controller? There is no "Títle" in attr. spector like other vc`s.

Comment: :) ViewController with title or the other one (in your question)?

Comment: make sure all is ok.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have the viewControllers in `UINavigationController`. Take `UINavigationController` first, and then add viewController in that. Once you have that and and add a segue from **VC1** to **VC2**, **Back** button would appear in the storyboard.